git merge-base HEAD <remote branch> doesn't return anything?
I'm cloning a certain branch of a repo. I then fetch a second branch. I ultimately want to run merge-base but every time I do it returns nothing:
git-init \
  -url="${PARAM_URL}" \
  -revision="test-branch" \
  -path="${CHECKOUT_DIR}" \
  -depth="1";
cd "${CHECKOUT_DIR}";
git fetch origin dev:refs/remotes/origin/dev;
git switch test-branch;
git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev;

The git merge-base command returns nothing. None of these are returning anything:
git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev;
git merge-base $(git rev-parse HEAD) remotes/origin/dev;
git merge-base remotes/origin/test-branch remotes/origin/dev;

I can see the branch with git branch and I can get the current commit with git rev-parse HEAD.
Ultimately, I just need to run this to get a list of files on the branch that differ from dev:
git diff --name-only HEAD $(git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev)

So why is HEAD not registering and how can I get it to work with HEAD?

The point of this is to get a list of modified files on test-branch that differ from dev. I basically just need to run git diff --name-only HEAD $(git merge-base HEAD remotes/origin/dev). It works on my PC but I'm trying to replicate it in a container in a pipeline and it's not working.

test-branch is tracking remotes/origin/test-branch

Your issue lies in : -depth="1"
In order to find the merge-base of two commits, git needs to inspect their history.
If you instructed git to only download the head commit for test-branch, well, you don't have its history.

The quick fix is: remove --depth=1 from your git init command, and download the entire history for your branch test-branch

side note: there is a syntax to access the diff between HEAD and "the merge base between branch dev and HEAD":
git diff --name-only dev...HEAD
# other shortcuts or implicit 'HEAD' also work:
git diff --name-only dev...@
git diff --name-only dev...

(documented in git help diff)
This is just syntactic sugar, this command still requires to scan the history of dev and "your active commit"

Unfortunately even without -depth I still get the same error. I tried git diff --name-only dev..HEAD and got ambiguous argument 'dev..HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree . I ran git remote show origin and see that remote branches test-branch and dev are both showing as tracked, but git branch shows * (HEAD detached at xyz123), I don't understand why it would be detached and not just on a branch.

I realize I only had 2 dots. Just tried with dev...HEAD and got the same error

@jeremywat oh: you explicitly fetch to ...:refs/remotes/origin/dev (as in: to the remote branch origin/dev). Use origin/dev...HEAD, or fetch to ...:refs/heads/dev (<- the dev branch)

In general, it could be that:

test-branch has been cloned or pulled with a depth level, git clone --depth=<n>, and therefore it doesn't contain its entire history. This is also your case, as git init is supplied to clone from the given remote with -depth="1";


Create a shallow clone with a history truncated to the specified number of commits. Implies --single-branch unless --no-single-branch is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches. If you want to clone submodules shallowly, also pass --shallow-submodules.


You've cloned the repository with just some branches and your local repo doesn't have the ancestor branch from which both test-branch and dev actually originate from.

The two branches have unrelated histories.


To fix your problem:

Delete the tracking branch remotes/origin/test-branch and then fetch it again. This will make sure that the entire history of test-branch will be fetched; otherwise, Git will try to retrieve only the new changes.

Hard reset the topic branch refs/heads/test-branch to the tracking branch refs/remotes/heads/test-branch. This will realign your local branch with its remote counterpart.


Before proceeding with the hard reset, make sure to save on a temporary branch any local changes of test-branch that are not on the remote.
# creating a new temporary branch with test-branch's history (and eventual local changes)
git checkout -b my_temp

# deleting the tracking branch
git branch --delete --remotes remotes/origin/test-branch

# fetching test-branch's history
git fetch origin test-branch

# checking out test-branch
git checkout test-branch

# bringing test-branch to the tip of its remote's counterpart
git reset --hard remotes/origin/test-branch

# cherry-picking any old local changes
git cherry-pick HEAD..my_temp

Now, you should be able to run git diff --name-only HEAD $(git merge-base test-branch dev) and retrieve the changes between the two.

In general, and this does not apply to your case, if the merge-base commit is on a branch that is not present in the local repository, you could:

Create a local branch for the remote's branch with the merge-base commit.

Fetch its changes.

Hard reset the local branch to its tracking branch.


# creating a local branch for the branch containing the merge-base commit
git branch other_branch

# fetching the other branch's history
git fetch origin other_branch

# checking out the other branch
git checkout other_branch

# resetting the other branch to its remote counterpart
git reset --hard remotes/origin/other_branch


Thanks I'll give this a try. This is being cloned from scratch in a container image so local changes are not an issue.
